# Set selected text in GWT (in order to make copy paste easier)

Tags: gwt, copy-paste

In GWT apparently you have to use some Flash-component to alter the clipboard. Since I don't want to use Flash, but I do want to copy and paste text from my application, I would like to set text selected if someone clicks on it. The only thing the user has to do is to type Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V to copy and paste (in Windows). Is this possible? How do I do this?

More info:

The app in which I would like to use this is at http://borkent-app2.appspot.com/.
It is an app I made to teach myself Hebrew words (my native language is Dutch). The Hebrew word is placed on the RootPanel using a Label. Sometimes I would like to copy and paste the Hebrew word (when I want to search on it in Google for example), but selecting it is somewhat cumbersome (probably because of the right-to-left text direction). So I would like to select the text of the Hebrew word by only clicking on the Label it is in.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the text a user should click on in a text area, a div or...? Some more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Label word = new Label("some text");
    word.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            markText(word.getElement());
        }
    });
    word.getElement().setId("test");
    RootPanel.get().add(word);
}

private native void markText(Element elem) /*-{
    if ($doc.selection && $doc.selection.createRange) {
        var range = $doc.selection.createRange();
        range.moveToElementText(elem);
        range.select();
    } else if ($doc.createRange && $wnd.getSelection) {
        var range = $doc.createRange();
        range.selectNode(elem);
        var selection = $wnd.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}-*/;
```

Comment: How can I set start/end offset? :/