# Gwt DragStartHandler does not work in IE and Firefox

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, firefox-addon

I have a FocusPanel in which contains a Label.
And then I add the DragStartHandler to FocusPanel like the code below:

```
focusPanel.addDomHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event)
            {
                focusPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("yellow");
                event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(focusPanel.getElement(), 10, 10);
                dragSourceIndex = getFocusPanelIndex(focusPanel);
            }
        }, DragStartEvent.getType());
```

I can drag this in Chrome, but cannot do this in IE and Firefox. Moreover, if I highlight the focuspanel's text first, then I can drag when it's highlighted.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I make a go-around by adding highlight on MouseDownEvent.

```
focusPanel.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
            {
                markText(focusPanel.getWidget().getElement());
            }
        });
```

The markText method is learn from here:
[Set selected text in GWT (in order to make copy paste easier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987824/set-selected-text-in-gwt-in-order-to-make-copy-paste-easier)

This is a hacking but at least works.
Now the issue is, the "drop" events are not happening in IE. I use IE 11.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Is this from a C++ firefox addon?